# Xcode: How to temporarily hide yellow warnings from Issue Navigator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working on a project (written by another developer...) with LOTS of yellow warnings.
During the build process, if there is a critical (red) error, the error keeps moving down beyond the bottom of the left pane, and it's always taking me some time until I can finally point the mouse at it and look at the error.
Is there a way of showing only the red (critical) errors?

Comment: Don't hide the warnings, resolve them. In most cases the compiler suggests what to do.

Comment: Resolve all the warnings one by one. Analyze your code. to find issues.

Comment: Basically you are both right, but I don't want to modify the other guy's code unless it's absolutely necessary (workplace politics).

Comment: People don't understand that fixing warning is not just a programming issue; It's more like a political issue.

Comment: Seeing all the warnings is really annoying when your code is still in progress and you're fully aware that you're not yet done.

Comment: Author clearly states he's working with code that's not his own and is asking a reasonable question. Telling him to fix all the warnings is not a reasonable response.

Comment: @ArikSegal Please review this question and mark your answer as the correct one. Jason's answer doesn't actually do what your question asked.

Comment: JohnnyLambada is correct. Additionally, fixing warnings should mean re-testing all of the changed components which may not be feasible for various reasons.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Toggle the **"!" button** (Show only errors) at the bottom right corner of the Issues Navigator to hide Warnings (next to the results filter).

[image: Filter Warnings Xcode 10]

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  I just wanted to see my compiler errors and not have to scroll below 100+ warnings.  Other answers talk about modifying project critical settings on a per warning type basis in build settings.  This is a simple UI switch that does the job.

Comment: This only turns off the warnings in the sidebar, not in the coding window.

Comment: When doing "Analyze" it shows warnings and the Analyze results, I wish I could filter out the warnings. The above mentioned trick is more like "only errors", instead of "warnings out".

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Project -> Your Project -> Search 'Warning'.
Then turn off warnings you don't want.

Comment: This should be the acceptable answer. However, I choose not to follow this solution, because I need the warnings while I'm working on my code.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, you should filter the warnings and only show errors for the short-term, and then you should fix all the warnings moving forward. From what I'm seeing, more warnings will slow down the build time in Xcode. Use [the solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405305/276626)

Comment: What do you mean by "Project"? This isn't a menu item and right-clicking on the name of my project doesn't bring up anything like "Search 'Warning'".

Answer (score 3):

***Xcode 11.7***,

handle ***Apple Clang Warning Policies***

image is more vivid.

[image: 1111]

Comment: A Picture is worth a Thousand Words!

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 14 you can hide some warnings while showing others.

In the Issue Navigator (Cmd-5) enter a word in the search field at the bottom and press Return. A down-arrow appears before the word that lets you select 'Contains', 'Does Not Contain', 'Begins With', and 'Ends With' for that word. Repeating these steps lets you add more qualified words to your search.

These searches are saved in a 'Recent Filters' menu that you can access by clicking on the left-most icon in this search field. There are also built-in filters in this menu such as 'not DEPRECATION'.

Useful for focusing on some fixing warnings before moving on to others.